# In a React Native stylesheet how can I group multiple styles together

Tags: react-native

I would like to combine shared styles together in React Native, if possible, like the way it's possible in a CSS stylesheet..

```
.one, .two {
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: green;
}
```

Currently, my React Native stylesheet looks like..

```
module.exports = {
    "one": {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start',
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    "two": {
        justifyContent: 'flex-end',
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    }
}
```

I could of course add multiple styles to an element..

```
module.exports = {
    "oneAndTwo": {
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    "one": {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    },
    "two": {
        justifyContent: 'flex-end'
    }
}

<View style={[styles.oneAndTwo, styles.one]}>
    <Text style={styles.oneAndTwoText}>One</Text>
</View>
<View style={[styles.oneAndTwo, styles.two]}>
    <Text style={styles.oneAndTwoText}>Two</Text>
</View>
```

..but I'm looking to see if its doable the CSS way.

***edit*** - thanks for the style management suggestions so far. I'll try them out over the weekend as I get more into React Native and reply back once I've had a chance to understand and apply them.

*It doesn't look like there is any simple method to style multiple style 'classes' like in css so I'll try the other ideas out.*

Comment: Thanks for the answers guys, sorry I've not been working on react native stuff since I posted this but when I put focus back into it I will go through each answer when I am better able to work through them and understand them.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest way I found to this this is like so. First I have a file which holds my variables

```js
/* styles/variables.js */
const styleVariables = {

  // Fonts
  baseFontSize: 16,
  largeFontSize: 24,

  // Icons
  smallIconSize: 24,
  mediumIconSize: 36,

  // Colors
  mainColor: '#e85e45',
  secondaryColor: '#a0c5d8',
  offWhite: '#f4f4f4',
  darkColor: '#404040',

  // Dimensions
  headerHeight: 70,
  shadowSize: 6
};
export default styleVariables;
```

And I reference my variables in other styling files where related information is grouped:

```js
/* styles/presentation.js */
import variables from './variables';

export const shadow = {
  shadowColor: variables.darkColor,
  shadowRadius: variables.shadowSize,
  shadowOpacity: 0.35,
  shadowOffset: {width: 0, height: 0}
};

export const centered = {
  alignItems: 'center'
  justifyContent: 'center'
}

export const button = {
    width: variables.buttonSize,
    height: variables.buttonSize,
    borderRadius: variables.buttonSize / 2,
}
```

And in then in my components I can combine those styles:

```js
import variables from './../styles/variables';
import {centered, shadow, button} from './../styles/presentation';

class RoundButton extends React.PureComponent {

  render() {
    return (
        <View style={styles.button}>
          {this.props.children}          
        </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    ...button,
    ...centered,
    ...shadow
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
    var {
        StyleSheet
      } = React;

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
          oneAndTwo: {
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: 'green'
    },
    one: {
        justifyContent: 'flex-start'
    },
       oneAndTwoText:{
        backgroundColor: 'green'
      }
      });

    <View style={[styles.oneAndTwo, styles.one]}>
        <Text style={styles.formButtonOutline}>One</Text>
    </View>
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript you should use `Object.assign()` to merge object.
Example:

```
        let justifyContent = {justifyContent: 'flex-start'};
        let alignItems = {alignItems: 'center'};
        let flex = {flex: 1};
        let backGroundColor = {backgroundColor: 'white'}

        let myStyle = Object.assign(justifyContent, alignItems, flex, backGroundColor)
        console.log(log_sign_data, myStyle)
```

Result:

```
 myStyle = {justifyContent: "flex-start", alignItems: "center", flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white"}
```